# Support Crystal report for hosting server

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reportviewer, web-hosting

I am running shared hosting server for asp.net application. I want to support for crystal report on my server. So that users web application use crystal report.

Can any one know what is the procedure to support crystal report on the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The report-viewer control (as of XIR2) is COM dependent.  Your hosting company will need to support COM and be willing to run the installation package to ensure that the correct registry entries are created.  I'm sure that there are licensing issues for this, not to mention the extra burden added to IIS for report processing.  You may want to consider BusinessObjects Enterprise.